# What are the rules regarding naming in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Are there definite rules regarding naming of entities in Haskell? (by entities I mean functions, term level variables, data constructors, type variables, type constructors, typeclasses, modules; not sure if I left something out here) For example

```
<interactive>:1:13: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Zed’
    Perhaps you meant type variable ‘zed’ (line 1)
```

I know that in type signatures concrete types must be uppercase. So is it assuming that `Zed` is a concrete type, and because this type isn't defined (isn't in scope), we get an error?

Are there any other actual rules on naming stuff in Haskell?

Comment: your first zed is lowercase, is that the problem?

Comment: Names of type constructors, data constructors, modules, and type classes must begin with an uppercase letter. Variable names (including type variables) must begin with a lowercase letter. This should be in any introductory text on Haskell.

Comment: Are you sure you have `;` and not `:` there? the errors seem to indicate otherwise. assuming the existence of a type `Zed` the code you wrote(here) should work in GHCi

Comment: Yes, in GHCi `Zed` should be defined before it is used. In .hs files it can be defined later on, but must be defined before the end of the file is reached.

Comment: @M.Aroosi do not assume `Zed` exists. It doesn't.

Comment: @n.m. I am following a textbook on Haskell, but I did not find a comprehensive table or something of this sort summarizing the style rules that are mandatory. Also did not find with a google search.

Comment: Ok, thanks @n.m., reason I said I didn't find it is I thought there were like a lotta rules, but I guess it's as simple as " Variable identifiers start with a lowercase letter, constructor identifiers with an uppercase letter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out by [M. Aroosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8491228/m-aroosi) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57423199/237428#comment101327335_57423199),  your errors don't match your example – you seem to have written `f :: zed -> Zed : f = undefined` instead, with a `:` instead of a `;`.  If you use a `;` you will get one of two results.  If `Zed` is undefined, you'll get an error telling you so:

```
Prelude> f :: zed -> Zed ; f = undefined

<interactive>:2:13: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Zed’
    Perhaps you meant type variable ‘zed’ (line 2)
```

If `Zed` is defined, everything will work:

```
Prelude> data Zed = TheZed
Prelude> f :: zed -> Zed ; f = undefined
Prelude>
```

The general rule for Haskell names is:

- At the type level:

  - Type names start with an uppercase letter.
  - Type variables start with a lowercase letter.
- At the term level:

  - Constructor names start with an uppercase letter if they're ordinary names.
  - Constructor infix operators start with a `:`.
  - Variable names start with a lowercase letter if they're ordinary names.
  - Variable infix operators start with anything but a `:`.

There are some further wrinkles (e.g., you can't use `,` in names; you can't have a name that's only `-`s and 2 or more character long), but that covers 95% of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the REPL (Ghci). If you try to use a type signature in the REPL, you need to use `:{ .....\n ..... \n ..... :}` kind of multiline input. Then you can do the type signature of the function along with implementation(s) of that type signature. Its not very practical - 1 typo and you have to do it all over again. (Julia language REPL does a much better job with that, btw.).

And yes, there are style guides and types need to start with an uppercase. Usually the compiler warns/errors you.

Since you seem to start out, I suggest you use a source file for your experiments because as soon as you end up with multiple line constructs, the REPL kind of sucks. And it is really easy to use a file for your code. See `:load :cd :reload` etc. for your GHCI commands which support you doing that.

Comment: GHCi hasn't required `:{ ... :}` for function signatures for a long time – try, e.g., `f :: a -> a ; f = id`.  You can also use the up and down arrows (or ⌃P/⌃N, and similar) to go back and forth between previously entered commands.  The question of upper-case letters isn't just stylistic, it's enforced by the language.  It is true that it's good to be working inside a file most of the time!  But the REPL is essential to experimentation and learning the language, IMHO.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky This year I did a small tour between various languages with REPLs. This even included common lisp / SLIME and it included Julia language - F Sharp and ocaml repls. And my take away from that tour is that indeed GHCI could use some love. Much love in fact. In Julia, for example you can simply enter multi line functions. And it has persistent command history. And if you go back in history, you get your WHOLE multilne function recalled and you can edit it in place. Line by line history like in haskell feels poor in contrast.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky And there are things like the conventions for indenting, which you CAN NOT learn in the GHCI alone (thanks to its line oriented limitations). And try to write a ``do block`` in one line... Actually I hardly ever use ``do`` notation even in files, because the indentation rules are cryptic and each time I try it is a waste of time.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Last not least, if the down vote is about me pointing out that  GHCI is not perfect, please undo it. Try entering multiple pattern matched versions of a single function signature in 1 line, if you really want to convince me ;)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky, you need those funny braces for multi-line input if you don't turn on the somewhat weird multi-line option.

Comment: @BitTickler Sure, GHCi could use work – I don't disagree with that, for sure.  But your comment about how GHCi behaves wrt type signatures and `:{`/`:}` is just wrong.  (And the question of "have to do it all over again" is arguable.)  And moreover, this doesn't address the questioner's problem as a result, since the code they have in their question _works_ given `data Zed`.

Comment: @dfeuer Multi-line input, yes; type signatures, no.  Type signatures are fine with just a semicolon entered on one line with the definition.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky, you can always use semicolons (and sometimes braces) to cut down to one line.